# What maintenance is required for a Postfix setup?

Tags: email, postfix, maintenance

I've taken a look at the setup and configuration process for a Postfix server, planning to use it for just sending emails out from my server. So far, I have these steps:

- Setup Postfix
- Configure Postfix
- Install DKIM
- Set SPF records
- Tune for performance
- Debug

Seems rather straightforward. However, I was just wondering: are there any actions I should be taking for periodic maintenance of my Postfix setup?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Also, just curious, how long would this entire setup ideally take? 30 - 60 minutes? More?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch the mail log for errors, but otherwise, nothing much.

Postfix has good, clear errors, so it is generally easy to figure out what went wrong and what the next step to take is.  One of the reasons I recommend it is exactly that.

Since you use SPF, you will have non-Postfix maintenance to do ensuring that users only ever send email from your domain through approved senders.

I would expect to spend ten to fifteen minutes doing the setup, so an hour for someone without much experience is reasonable.

Comment: What sort of errors are common? And I wouldn't be allowing any other users to send through the app, just transactional or notification emails. Thanks for your time though!

Comment: Watch for spikes in delivery failure, since that can indicate problems with, eg, DNS resolution.  Watch for fatal errors.  Generally the problems are very obvious, because Postfix has good, clear error messages.